# Find the minimum integer i that there exist an integer in segment[i*a, i*b]

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, real-numbers

It is a problem from CCPC2017 in Harbin. Give two number a, b, $0<a<b<1$ and the precision of a, b are less than 300 decimal places. The question is that find the minmum integer i that there exists an interger in the segement $[i*a, i*b]$. I didn't find a efficient way to search the answer. Since the answer may be very big($a=10^{-300}, b=2*10^{-300}, answer= 5*10^{299}$).I tried binary research, but found it is not suitable for this problem.